# How do I reverse this pattern using nested loop?

Tags: python

I am new to programming and nested for loops are driving me crazy. After a lot of time I was able to draw this pattern:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
```

```
for i in range(6):
    for j in range(i+1):
        print(j+1,end="")
    print()
```

As I understood, when i is 0 in the first iteration, range for inner loop would be 1 and (j+1) would print 1. And I got the pattern.

I can't do the flip of this pattern like:

```
      1
     21
    321
   4321
  54321
 654321

# Code I tried was:
for i in range(6,0,-1):
    for j in range(i): 
        print(' ',end="")
    print()

# The above is just printing blank spaces.
```

I want to use nested for loops for this problem.

Comment: sorry I edited the pattern I wanted. my mistake.

Comment: You never print `i` in the second program.

Comment: couple hints: first off, for each row, which loop is controlling the maximum  value printed? (answer: notice that it's the *outer* loop that is essentially deciding the max values for each row, because the inner loop depends on the outer one. So, in your second version, should `i` start from 6 or 0?). Second: In your second version, you never have a print for digits, so naturally, it would only print spaces. See if these two hints get you somewhere.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh I think the inner loop should start from 6 because I am printing 5 spaces in the first row.

Comment: @Cruise5 good, agreed, inner loop is printing numbers in reverse order, no issues with it starting from 6. What about the outer one?

Comment: @ParitoshSingh hmm I guess it should start with 6 as well because it's printing 6 rows. As I understand, the outer loop is for columns and inner for rows.

Comment: @Cruise5 there's an issue there, because there are 6 rows and 6 columns in *total*. But what the value of the loop should *start* from, has no relation to the total number of rounds the loop does. Consider, going from 0 to 5, or 6 to 1, *both* give you 6 rounds of iteration. So, you're mixing up the "total number of iterations" with "starting value". The starting value is controlling something more specific. Refer to my hint as well

Comment: Or, simply put, let's look at your first example: It has 6 rows and 6 columns as well. Why didn't the loop start from 6 there?

Comment: @ParitoshSingh. Well when i is 0 in the first iteration, range of j is 1 so j becomes 0, and j+1 is printing 1, then 2 in second iteration of inner loop

Comment: @Cruise5 So, the outer loop is starting from 0, and going up, because you need to print only 1 at first, then upto 2, then so on yes?. Look at the 2nd one again, do you need to print only 1 at first, then upto 2, then so on? Essentially, ascending or descending? Hope that helps. You have an answer to the question now as well if you just want the answer. But it will help to develop an intuitive reasoning for what values the loops should start and end from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your outer loop should count up. The inner loop should print `6-i` spaces, then print the digits from `i` to `1` descending.

```
end = 6
for i in range(1, end+1):
    print(" "*(end-i), end="")
    for j in range(i, 0, -1):
        print(j, end="")
    print()
```

Comment: I was going through pythontutor to visualize each step. In first iteration, i in the outer loop is 1 and then it will print 5 spaces. Now, for the inner loop, i is still one and the range (i, 0, -1) confuses me. How can j be 1 here? The range(1,0,-1) would equal to what values?

Comment: Ok, I executed `for j in range(1, 0, -1):
    print(j)` and it's giving me an answer 1 but I don't understand the negative counting here that gives 1

Comment: The third argument is how much to add to the variable each time. If it's negative it counts down.

Comment: The first time `j = 1`, it prints `1`. Then it adds `-1`, which results in `0`. That's where it stops.